# Keep log file of shell script execution until past few days

Tags: unix, shell, standard-error

Am appending the standard output and error of the shell script execution on a unix bok like shown below

```
/home/mydir/shellScript.sh >> /home/mydir/shellScript.log 2>&1
```

Now am wondering a way to keep logs going back as much as say 30 days else the log file size will keep on increasing.
Would appreciate if anyone can provide recommendations around the same.

Comment: Why don't you put a date by each log entry, and read in the last date when writing to it, if it's past 30 days, truncate the file to that end, then append?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is this a long-running script (e.g. daemon)? Or does it do something then exits quickly? You could dynamically build the log file's name based on today's date, so a new file gets generated any time the date changes:

```
#/bin/sh
now=`date +%F`
/home/mydir/shellScript.sh >> /home/mydir/shellScript-$now.log 2>&1
previous=`date --date='30 days ago' +%F`
rm -f /home/mydir/shellScript-$previous.log 2>&1
```

(added stale log removal).

Comment: Interesting! However i need to add this entry in crontab file.

Comment: No reason you can't have this in another shell script, which you add to the crontab. One script can easily call another.

Comment: Won't the log file keep getting accumulated this way? Do i have to purge them?

Comment: They will, you'd have to remove old ones, which could also be done in the same shell script. The `date` command can take relative commands, like `date --date='30 days ago'`, from which you can build older log filenames and rm them.

Comment: Can you please edit your initial response and show everything in one script taking one week as an example. That would surely help!

Answer (score 4):

This kind of thind is generally done with a tool such as [**`logrotate`**](http://linux.die.net/man/8/logrotate).

For example, with Apache's logs, I've seen it used to :

- Once per day, move the current file to another (to have one log file per day), gzipping the resulting file of the day before
- Delete the archived file that were more than 1 week old

So, I suppose you might be able to use it to get what you're asking.

Comment: Any references on logrotate preferably with examples that can help me get up to speed quickly.

Answer (score 1):

Pascal MARTIN is correct - it is a simple matter to put a configuration file into `/etc/logrotate.d`, or add an entry onto the end of the file `/etc/logrotate`, as `logrotate` is included stock in most UNIX systems. It is a very easy-to-understand configuration file that takes roughly 5 min. at a man page to understand. I recommend it as the easiest and most maintainable solution.

Answer (score 0):

There's not a lot of context to your problem included.

I agree with both of the offered solutions.

I would also point you to my 2 rather long-winded ;-) discourses on naming and managing logfiles.

[Bash piping output and input of a program](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5449231/bash-piping-output-and-input-of-a-program/5450711#5450711)

[command line wisdom for 2 panel file manager user](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5602218/command-line-wisdom-for-2-panel-file-manager-user/5602467#5602467)

I hope these help.